# Dynamic SQL - Invalid object name error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using dynamic SQL on SQL Server 2008 to select specified columns from a row but I keep getting the following error:

> Invalid object name 'Form'

My code is as follows:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'select 
[City],[Place]'
+
'
from Form where [Age:] =  20'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

I also tried using `+ QUOTENAME(@Table)` and declared`@Table` as `nvarchar(MAX)` but could not define that `@Table` is basically the `Form` table in my database.

As I checked the previous [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833352/declare-variable-for-query-string), people were able to select columns from tables the same way without getting errors, so what could be the reason for the error I get? Should I use `@QUOTENAME` function at all?

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: You describe @table?  Where is this in your query?

Comment: what is `Form` ? is this your table name ?

Comment: Did you check if you have a table by name `Form`?

Comment: First of all, I am sure I do have a table that is called `Form` because I can do basic operations on it. And I have also removed @Table declaration because I could not set @Table to my Form table in database.

Comment: @Nisarg How can I check if executing user have permissions on the table? Is there any other permissions to specify in order select from table in Dynamic Programming? I am basically able to do any of the operations I want to do on every database on my SQL Server.

Comment: do a `PRINT @SQL`, copy the result and paste into a new query window and execute. Any error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below query and if you still get error check basic things first.

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'select [City],[Place] from [Form] where [Age] =  20'
EXEC (@SQL)
```

1. Is table `[Form]` present in database ?
2. Are you running in correct DB?
3. I see `":"` after AGE is that in col name ?
4. If Age is varchar try to add "'" before and after 20.

Comment: It is solved sir, thank you. I should have checked the syntax better since there is no correction system in Dynamic Programming because we write queries in quotation marks. The database I have imported was called `'Form'`, not `Form` (as also @Nisarg has warned me) . The rest of query was written true.

Answer (score 1):

You describe `@table`.  Table is a reserved keyword, so it's a good practice not to use that word.  Lets assume `@mytable` is a variable containing the table name for the query.  In that case, you concatenate like you do with the rest of the string.  **You also need to be connected to the database you are trying to query from.**

For example:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @mytable varchar(1000) = 'Form' --put the table name here

SET @SQL = 'select [City], [Place] '
         + 'from ' + @mytable + ' where [Age:] =  20'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: even though `table` is a reserved word, there is nothing wrong using variable `@table` at all

Comment: True. But if you declare a variable in this manner it will highlight `@table` with the reserved keyword color in stackoverflow.  Also, you can use reserved keywords with brackets... example `CREATE [TABLE] TABLE (...)`, which is valid- but any DBA is going to tell you not to do it.